# Ставится ли запятая перед «в чём»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Осознать, в чём ваша уникальность.*

Нужно ли ставить запятую в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2):

Да, в этом сложноподчиненном предложении перед "в чем" запятая должна быть.

> **1.** Придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения выделяется запятыми...
> **2.** В составе сложноподчиненного предложения могут быть неполные предложения:
> <...> *Трудно было понять, **в чём дело**; Готов помочь, **чем смогу**; Постепенно научились разбираться, **что к чему**...*

[Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

*Осознать, в чём ваша уникальность.*

***Осознать, в чём** оно, это что-то, пока ещё возможно, ― пока не сделан следующий шаг в глубину текста* (Владислав Отрошенко. Эссе из книги «Тайная история творений» // «Октябрь», 2001).
***Осознать, в чем** ваша ценность* (Лидия Гордеева. Путь к изобилию).
*Созвониться с Серегой, **понять, в чем** дело ― в войне или в выборах* (Татьяна Устинова. Персональный ангел).